# C#:docx generated from html by open xml power tools throw pre release 2007

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-powertools

I'm writing code that get the content of Docx file as HTML by using open XML power tools and now I want to convert it back to another docx file. the step that gets contents as HTML works fine but when I generate the docx file from that HTML the file cannot be opened and throws this error

> this file was created in a pre-release version of word 2007 and cannot
>   be opened in this version

the HTML generated from test docx is

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta
      charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>My Page Title</title>
    <meta
      name="Generator"
      content="PowerTools for Open XML" />
    <style>span { white-space: pre-wrap; }
p.pt-Normal {
    line-height: 107.9%;
    margin-bottom: 8pt;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: ;
    font-size: 11pt;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
span.pt-DefaultParagraphFont {
    font-family: ;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
span.pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000000 {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p
        dir="rtl"
        class="pt-Normal">&#x200f;<span
          lang="fa-IR"
          class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont">&#x200f;با سلام خدمت &#x200f;</span><span
          lang="fa-IR"
          class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont">&#x200f;&lt;&lt;&#x200f;</span><span
          class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000000">&#x200e;PERSONS.lname&#x200e;</span><span
          lang="fa-IR"
          class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont">&#x200f;&gt;&gt;&#x200f;</span><span
          lang="fa-IR"
          class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont">&#x200f; &#x200f;</span><span
          lang="fa-IR"
          class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont">&#x200f;&lt;&lt;&#x200f;</span><span
          class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000000">&#x200e;PERSONS.fname&#x200e;</span><span
          lang="fa-IR"
          class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont">&#x200f;&gt;&gt;&#x200f;</span></p>
      <p
        dir="rtl"
        class="pt-Normal">&#x200f;<span
          lang="fa-IR"
          class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont">&#x200f;مدیر محترم &#x200f;</span><span
          lang="fa-IR"
          class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont">&#x200f;&lt;&lt;&#x200f;</span><span
          class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000000">&#x200e;OFFICE.name&#x200e;</span><span
          lang="fa-IR"
          class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont">&#x200f;&gt;&gt;&#x200f;</span></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my code to save the above html as docx is

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc =
        WordprocessingDocument.Create(dest_doc_path, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {


                MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();

                string htmlcontent = htmlTXT.Text;

                using (Stream stream = mainPart.GetStream())
                {
                    byte[] buf = (new UTF8Encoding()).GetBytes(htmlcontent);
                    stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                }


                MessageBox.Show("DONE", "done", MessageBoxButton.OK);


            }
```

Comment: Do you have further queries or does the answer below help solve your problem?

Comment: yes...how ever i could not get xml of docx directly ... and for now i follow these steps as  rename the file from .docx format to zip format and then i can find xml file of docx in word folder .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple. You **must not** insert HTML content into the `MainDocumentPart` because it is expected to contain a valid Open XML `w:document` element, e.g., as the following simplified one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Hello, world!</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

The error message probably is a little misleading. HTML is simply invalid in this case.

Depending on whether or not you changed the HTML after creating it (with the Open XML PowerTools) from the original Word document, you will have to either transform it back into valid Open XML markup (if you changed it) or simply use the Open XML markup from the original Word document.